# anyway to reduce my textbox common code

Tags: c#

I have a form in which there are many textboxes (in tabControl layout). I am disabling right click function on all the textboxes. by giving the below code:

```
        txtAmountChildPlans.ContextMenu = new ContextMenu();
        txtCityHome.ContextMenu = new ContextMenu();
        txtCityPersonal.ContextMenu = new ContextMenu();
        txtCityRetirement.ContextMenu = new ContextMenu();
        txtEmailCar.ContextMenu = new ContextMenu();
        txtEmailCarIns.ContextMenu = new ContextMenu();
        txtEmailHome.ContextMenu = new ContextMenu();
        txtEmailOp.ContextMenu = new ContextMenu();
        txtEmailPersonal.ContextMenu = new ContextMenu();
        txtEmailSenior.ContextMenu = new ContextMenu();
        txtEmailTwoIns.ContextMenu = new ContextMenu();
        txtFullNamePersonal.ContextMenu = new ContextMenu();
        txtManufacturerCar.ContextMenu = new ContextMenu();
        txtMobileCar.ContextMenu = new ContextMenu();
        txtMobileCarIns.ContextMenu = new ContextMenu();
        txtMobileHome.ContextMenu = new ContextMenu();
        txtMobileNoRetirement.ContextMenu = new ContextMenu();
        txtMobileOp.ContextMenu = new ContextMenu();
        txtMobilePersonal.ContextMenu = new ContextMenu();
        txtMobileSenior.ContextMenu = new ContextMenu();
        txtMobileTwoIns.ContextMenu = new ContextMenu();
        txtModelCar.ContextMenu = new ContextMenu();
        txtMonthlySalaryCar.ContextMenu = new ContextMenu();
        txtNameHome.ContextMenu = new ContextMenu();
        txtNameRetirement.ContextMenu = new ContextMenu();
        txtPensionRetirement.ContextMenu = new ContextMenu();
        txtRegCarIns.ContextMenu = new ContextMenu();
        txtRegTwoIns.ContextMenu = new ContextMenu();
```

EDIT:

```
        foreach (var textbox in this.Controls.OfType<TextBox>())
        {
            textbox.ContextMenu = new ContextMenu();
        }
        foreach (var textbox in this.tabCarInsurance.Controls.OfType<TextBox>())
        {
            textbox.ContextMenu = new ContextMenu();
        }
        foreach (var textbox in this.tabHealth.Controls.OfType<TextBox>())
        {
            textbox.ContextMenu = new ContextMenu();
        }
        foreach (var textbox in this.tabHomeLoans.Controls.OfType<TextBox>())
        {
            textbox.ContextMenu = new ContextMenu();
        }
        foreach (var textbox in this.tabRetirement.Controls.OfType<TextBox>())
        {
            textbox.ContextMenu = new ContextMenu();
        }
```

Is there anyway to write this in sigle function. or less code?

This doesnt look good to me. Is there any way in c# like in css to give the same property to all the textboxes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can enumerate throuh all textboxes and create new context menu in loop

```
foreach (TextBox textbox in AllTextBoxes(this))
{
    textbox.ContextMenu = new ContextMenu();
}

public IEnumerable<TextBox> AllTextBoxes(Control control)
{
    List<TextBox> result = new List<TextBox>();
    result.AddRange(control.Controls.OfType<TextBox>());
    foreach (var childControl in control.Controls.OfType<Control>())
    {
        result.AddRange(AllTextBoxes(childControl));
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for response. where should i write this code. I am beginner in .net. I wrote it in form load event but not working.

Comment: That depends on what you wish to do, do you want to disable it when the form is loaded? or at the occurrence of a particular event?

Comment: Works fine in constructor after InitializeComponent()

Comment: no still not working. given below initializeComponent();  i have tabcontrol inside another tabcontrol.

Comment: It works fine everywhere after initialization of controls. This code may not work, because it apllies only to textboxes on the main form.  You should select controls from your controls container, not from this.Controls

Comment: ohh k i understand. let me check.

Comment: yeah working. just a small question.. is there anyway to write it in single line like `foreach(var textbox in this.Controls.OfType<TabControl>().ofType<TextBox>())` (this is not working)  so that it take tabcontrols also into consideration.

Comment: To get them in one line you can use SelectMany. foreach (TextBox textbox in this.Controls.OfType<TabControl>().SelectMany(tc => tc.Controls.OfType<TabPage>().SelectMany(page => page.Controls.OfType<TextBox>()))) but you should better use recursive control obtaining from PHeiberg answer

Comment: no this is not working. the problem with pheiberg answer is that i cant understand it. still trying to understand it.

Comment: I have simplified PHeiberg answer. Take a look

Comment: "An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll" at `result.AddRange(control.Controls.OfType<TextBox>());`

Comment: and even i can call this form as an object to other form. If i do that it showing the same error at `objForm.ShowDialog()`.

Comment: if i change it to `Show` from `ShowDialog()`. the error is showing at the `result.AddRange....`

Comment: I asked the extended question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12895885/1577396)

Answer (score 4):

Provided that there are no nested controls you could do something along these lines:

```
foreach(var textbox in Controls.OfType<TextBox>())
{   
    textbox.ContextMenu = new ContextMenu();
}
```

If you must handle nested controls you can do so using an extension method

```
public static class ControlExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> AllControlsOfType<T>(this Control control) 
        where T : Control
    { 
         T found = control as T;
         if(found != null)
         {
             yield return found;
         } 

         foreach (var child in control.Controls.Cast<Control>())
         {
            foreach (var item in AllControls<T>(child))
            {
               yield return item;
            }
         }
    }
}
```

which can be used by this code in your form

```
foreach(var textbox in this.AllControlsOfType<TextBox>())
{   
    textbox.ContextMenu = new ContextMenu();
}
```

Make sure to reference the namespace that holds the Extension method.

Comment: Thank you for response. where should i write this code. I am beginner in .net. I wrote it in form load event but not working.

Comment: i have tabcontrol inside a tab control.

Comment: VS is showing red scribbles to `AllControls<T>` ERROR: doesnot exist.

Comment: The Extension method would go in a separate static class. I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a method like below.

```
private void AssignDataContext(params TextBox[] textboxes)
{
    foreach (var textbox in textboxes)
    {
        textbox.ContextMenu = new ContextMenu();
    }
}
```