# give same property to all textbox controls

Tags: c#

how to give same property to all textboxes present in the same form.

```
      foreach (var textbox in this.Controls.OfType<TextBox>())
        {
            textbox.ContextMenu = new ContextMenu();
        }
```

The above code works only if the textboxes are not in nested format.

In my project I have multiple tabpages in tabcontrol. so i cant implement the above code. but i can implement the below code:

```
      foreach (TextBox textbox in this.Controls.OfType<TabControl>().SelectMany(tc => tc.Controls.OfType<TabPage>().SelectMany(page => page.Controls.OfType<TextBox>())))
        {
            textbox.ContextMenu = new ContextMenu();
        }
        foreach (var textbox in this.tabCarInsurance.Controls.OfType<TextBox>())
        {
            textbox.ContextMenu = new ContextMenu();
        }
        foreach (var textbox in this.tabHomeLoans.Controls.OfType<TextBox>())
        {
            textbox.ContextMenu = new ContextMenu();
        }
        foreach (var textbox in this.tabRetirement.Controls.OfType<TextBox>())
        {
            textbox.ContextMenu = new ContextMenu();
        }
```

Here I am implementing for each tabControl. which still i dont like (because I have more tab pages to take care of). Is there anyway to reduce the above code.

I tried the below code: (*not working*)

```
       foreach (var textbox in this.Controls.OfType<TabControl>().OfType<TextBox>())
        {
            textbox.ContextMenu = new ContextMenu();
        }
```

I got the above code knowledge from my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12894451/1577396).

Please Help

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 private void SetProperty(Control ctr)
    {
        foreach(Control control in ctr.Controls)
        {
            if (control is TextBox)
            {
                control.ContextMenu = new ContextMenu();               
            }
            else
            {
                if (control.HasChildren)
                {
                    SetProperty(control);
                }                    
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for response. it is showing red scribbles to `ctr`. Please explain i am beginner in c#.

Comment: @Anandkumar, are you expecting `TextBox` to have children??))

Comment: ya it is not showing any scribbles now. where to call this function and how. please explain.

Comment: Yes its working. thank you very much :) mention that in answer also so that some users like me will not get confuse.

Comment: can i make it as a class library so that i can use it in future? (i tried to make but it is showing red scribbles to `control`) -- am I missing some reference here? please help.

Comment: i think your missing 
--------    using System.Windows.Forms on the top

Answer (score 1):

Just use the recursion to go through all controls subcollections:

```
void SetControl(ContextMenu menu, Control control)
{
    if (control is TextBox)
        control.ContextMenu = menu;
    else
    {
        foreach (Control c in control.Controls)
            SetControl(menu, c);
    }
}
```

It will find all the textboxes and set one and the same context menu to all of them.

You mal call it,say, from form's OnLoad event handler. While it's assumed that you have `yourContextMenu` defined for the form.

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SetControl(yourContextMenu, this);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

How about an extension method to do it, called from your tabcontrol container...

```
public static class ControlExtensions
{
    public static void SetContextMenuOnChildTextBoxes(this Control control)
    {
        if (control is TextBox)
        {
            control.ContextMenu = new ContextMenu();
        }
        if (control.Controls != null)
        {
            foreach (Control controlChild in control.Controls)
            {
                controlChild.SetContextMenuOnChildTextBoxes();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This could be put in a common area of code so that it could be called from any parents that wanted this functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
private void CtxMenu(Control parent)
{
    foreach (Control child in parent.Controls)
    {
        if (child is TextBox)
        {
            (child as TextBox).ContextMenu = new ContextMenu(); 
        }
}
```