# How to apply a textbox formatting method to all textbox controls

Tags: c#, textbox, windows-forms-designer, masking

OK, so I am trying to apply the accounting number format for all textboxes on my Form.

Now, I did some research here and found this post that will help me to set the [format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19215989/textbox-for-price-cash-currency-on-c-sharp).

And then I found another post to apply the format for all textbox [controls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12895885/give-same-property-to-all-textbox-controls?answertab=oldest#tab-top) on the form without adding the [format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19215989/textbox-for-price-cash-currency-on-c-sharp) code individually to all controls.

Well, the thing is that the code on the [format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19215989/textbox-for-price-cash-currency-on-c-sharp) uses the control name, which will bind it to a single textbox control. I tried the control name (TextoBox) instead, and it also failed.

There is another issue to consider, that even if I manage to get past the above problem, the code from [format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19215989/textbox-for-price-cash-currency-on-c-sharp) is an event, named after the control name, so I do not think it will work if I apply it to a class or method and call for it.

While I already do have the solution to what I want, I would like to know if there is a faster way to apply it, which will not add so much lines to my code. Trying to learn how to keep things easier to read, doing less with more. Any advise?

Thanks for reading.

Comment: If accounting is truly important, I would suggest using the Decimal type instead of Double. Double will be faster, but Decimal is more precise. Figure out which trade off makes sense and make a decision based on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you have all the pieces, just need help putting it together. For the ControlName, you can cast the sender object to the control and access its Name property.

```
void SetProperty(Control ctr)
{
    foreach (Control control in ctr.Controls)
    {
        if (control is TextBox)
        {
            control.Leave += control_Leave;
        }
        else
        {
            if (control.HasChildren)
            {
                SetProperty(control);
            }
        }
    }
}

void control_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var textBox = sender as TextBox;
    Double value;
    if (Double.TryParse(textBox.Text, out value))
        textBox.Text = String.Format(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, "{0:C2}", value);
    else
        textBox.Text = String.Empty;
}
```

Usage:

```
SetProperty(this);
```

Also, from my comment on the OP: If accounting is truly important, I would suggest using the Decimal type instead of Double. Double will be faster, but Decimal is more precise. Figure out which trade off makes sense and make a decision based on that.

---

Edit per comments:

```
myTextBox.Leave -= control_Leave
```

If you know the name of the control, the above will work. You will need to do this after you use SetProperty(this). If you want to handle this inside the SetProperty() method, do a check on control.Name == "myTextBox".

Comment: It worked perfectly! Thanks so much for helping me out!

Comment: Now, quick question, what if I want to have a single textbox control set without the formatting? I tried:
Mytextbox.Text = String.Format("{0}",txbTrackingID.Text);
played around with some variations of the above and some other information I found on CurrentCulture on MSDN but it didn't worked out.

Comment: You would need some way to identify this textbox specifically and handle it differently. If you know the control, you can unhook the even handler. See my edit.

Answer (score 0):

You can subscribe multiple controls event(that use the same args) to the same event handler :

```
public YourFormConstructor()
{
    foreach(var textbox in form.Controls.OfType<TextBox>())
        textbox.Leave += FormatCurrencyText;
}


private void FormatCurrencyText(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var textbox = sender as TextBox;
    Double value;
    if (Double.TryParse(textbox.Text, out value))
        textbox.Text = String.Format(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, "{0:C2}", value);
    else
        textbox.Text = String.Empty;
}
```